# Plotting circles around points in animation plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation

I'm plotting some points moving in a 2D space and I want to add circles around them. I have all the x,y coordinates for the points around which the circles are supposed to be plotted, but I am unsure how to add this into the animate function.

Any help would be appreciated!

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from launcher import sol, T, dt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation, PillowWriter
from create import p, N, walls_x, walls_y

# convert sol.y to plottable array('s) using smart slicing
def sol_convert(sol):
    #T = len(sol.t)                      # amount of time steps
    x = sol.y[0::4,:]                   # there are 4 values p.p. (x,y,vx,vy)
    y = sol.y[1::4,:]
    vx = sol.y[2::4,:]
    vy = sol.y[3::4,:]
    
    return x, y, vx ,vy

r_x, r_y, v_x, v_y = sol_convert(sol)


fig, ax = plt.subplots()

xlimit, ylimit = [-1,26], [-1,16]
axis = plt.axes(xlim =(xlimit),
                ylim =(ylimit))

for i in range(len(walls_x)):
    plt.plot(walls_x[i],walls_y[i],'k',linestyle="solid")
 
ped, = axis.plot([], [], 'o')

# what will our line dataset contain?
def init():
    ax.set_xlim(xlimit)
    ax.set_ylim(ylimit)
    ped.set_data([], [])
    return ped,
 
# initializing empty values for x and y co-ordinates
xdata, ydata = [], []

# animation function
def animate(frame):
    # t is a parameter which varies
    # with the frame number
    t = dt * frame

    xdata = r_x[:,frame]
    ydata = r_y[:,frame]
    ped.set_data(xdata, ydata)
    circles = plt.Circle((r_x[:,frame],r_y[:,frame]),2,color='r', fill=False)
    ax.add_patch(circles)   

    return ped,

anim = FuncAnimation(fig, animate,
                            init_func = init,
                            frames = T,
                            interval = 20,
                            blit = True)
 
# saves the animation in our desktop
writergif = PillowWriter(fps=24)
anim.save('pedestrians.gif',writer=writergif)
```

I've tried adding code within the animate function, but I am very new to animation plotting and do not fully grasp what type of data can be given through this function.

Here is a minimal reproducible example:

```py
# Minimal reproducable example
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation, PillowWriter

# simulation variables
sim_time = 4       # total simulation time in [?] [is it in steps or in s]
dt = 0.5            # time step of the simulation in s
t = np.arange(0,sim_time,dt)            # live running time of simulation
t_span = [t[0],t[-1]]
T = len(t)                              # amount of time steps for frames


fig, ax = plt.subplots()

xlimit, ylimit = [-1,26], [-1,16]
axis = plt.axes(xlim =(xlimit),
                ylim =(ylimit))

 
points, = axis.plot([], [], 'o')

# what will our line dataset contain?
def init():
    ax.set_xlim(xlimit)
    ax.set_ylim(ylimit)
    points.set_data([], [])
    return points,
 
# initializing empty values for x and y co-ordinates
xdata, ydata = [], []

# animation function
def animate(frame):
    # t is a parameter which varies
    # with the frame number
    t = dt * frame

    xdata = np.random.rand(3)*10
    ydata = np.random.rand(3)*10
    points.set_data(xdata, ydata)
    circles = plt.Circle((xdata,ydata),2,color='r', fill=False)
    ax.add_patch(circles)   

    return points,

anim = FuncAnimation(fig, animate,
                            init_func = init,
                            frames = T,
                            interval = 20,
                            blit = True)
 
# saves the animation in our desktop
writergif = PillowWriter(fps=24)
anim.save('pedestrians.gif',writer=writergif)
```

Comment: Could you please post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: I've added a MRC version underneath with some randomized (x,y) values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `plt.circle` (which seems to me is not supported in Matplotlib v3.5.1), please use [`matplotlib.patches.Circle`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.patches.Circle.html#matplotlib.patches.Circle) to draw circles.

[`plt.subplots`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots.html) draws a figure and returns an array of Axes objects. By default, the function call returns one Axes object, which is referred here as `ax`.

At the beginning of every frame, we have to make sure previous circles are erased from the `ax`. Thus, we use [`plt.cla()`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.cla.html#matplotlib.pyplot.cla) which erases the entire `ax` but we quickly plot the new data using [`ax.plot`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.plot.html) and set its axes limits using `ax.set_xlim` and `ax.set_ylim`.

Circles need to be added to the `ax` one by one since using [`ax.add_patch`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.add_patch.html) since `matplotlib.patches.Circle` creates only one circle at a time. Using a loop, we draw circles around centres (using *xdata* and *ydata*).

However, given the length of x- and y-axes are not equal (27 units vs. 17 units), the circles drawn will be ellipses as x-axis is stretched as compared to y-axis: you can confirm this by commenting out [`ax.set_aspect("equal")`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_aspect.html) in the code below. However, scaling the axes properly gives us appropriate circles.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
from matplotlib.patches import Circle

t = np.arange(0, 4, 0.5)            
T = len(t)                   

xdata, ydata = [], []
xlimit, ylimit = [-1,26], [-1,16]

fig, ax = plt.subplots(layout='tight')
points, = ax.plot(xdata, ydata, 'o')

ax.set_xlim(xlimit)
ax.set_ylim(ylimit)

def init():
    points, = ax.plot(xdata, ydata, 'o')
    return points, 

def animate(frame):
    xdata = np.random.rand(3)*10
    ydata = np.random.rand(3)*10
    
    # Clear the current Axes to make sure circles drawn in the latest animation are erased
    plt.cla()

    ax.plot(xdata, ydata, 'o')
    ax.set_xlim(xlimit)
    ax.set_ylim(ylimit)

    # To make sure circles are actually circles, and not ellipses
    ax.set_aspect("equal")

    # Draw circles one by one on the current Axes
    for i in range(3):
        circle = Circle((xdata[i], ydata[i]), 2, color='r', fill=False)
        ax.add_patch(circle)

    return points, 
    
anim = FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames=T, interval=100, blit=True)
plt.show()
```

This gives:
[image]

An alternative method would store circles drawn at every frame and make them [invisible](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.artist.Artist.set_visible.html#matplotlib.artist.Artist.set_visible) before a new frame is drawn, along with using `fig.canvas.draw()`:

```
circles = {}
ax.set_aspect("equal")

def animate(frame):
    global circles

    xdata = np.random.rand(3)*10
    ydata = np.random.rand(3)*10

    for i in circles.keys():
        circles[i].set_visible(False)

    for i in range(3):
        circles[i] = Circle((xdata[i], ydata[i]), 2, color='r', fill=False)
        ax.add_patch(circles[i])

    points, = ax.plot(xdata, ydata, 'o', color='b')
    fig.canvas.draw()
    return points,
```

Comment: Thanks! It works now. I had to redo a couple of things, but it now all plots via plt.plot, instead of set_data. Do you happen to know if this affects loading time when the datasets get large?

Comment: @ischokking I haven't really tested the code with more data points, so only drawing the points and corresponding circles will answer the question. :)